# Write two decimal numbers in same lenth

Tags: python

I have two decimal number with different digit places ( like 3.60 and 12.750),
I am going to have then in the output with the same length such as following (in this case both of them have 7 characters):

3.60000 and 12.7500

Comment: Show your effort please

Answer (score 1):

```
nums = [3.60, 12.750]

for num in nums:
    s = "%.5f" % num  # 5 because it's 7-2
    s = s[:7]  # Accounts for the '.'
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
3.60000
12.7500
# Each has length 7.
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Have you even tried your solution? Gives 00003 and 00012.

Comment: @Julien Thanks! Fixed it :)

Comment: Still not what OP is asking for.

Comment: `print("%.5f" % num)` instead of `print("%.5d" % num)`

Comment: This gives me 3.60000 and 12.75000 with the same number of digits, but I want 3.600000 and 12.7500 with the same character

Comment: @HosseinKianimehr But it does give the same number of characters. Check it again.